# Overriding Android Back button action in FlutterFlow

Tags: android, flutter, flutterflow

For a page, I only see two options to perform actions - "On Page Load" & "On Phone Shake". But I need to perform an action on press of Android back button or back gesture (swipe from the edges). I can write my own custom action, but the problem is I am not aware how to add that trigger (on back press) in FlutterFlow.

Has anyone done similar thing? Any pointers?

[image: FlutterFlow Action Flow Editor]